# what's the meaning of "run" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I would like to know if run in this context means organize (like organize an event).

"I watched four volleyball games running simultaneously"
Thanks

Comment: No. Your suggested meaning would apply in, for example, *I **ran** four volleyball games simultaneously*. But in the cited context, ***running = active = taking place = happening = being played***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **run** an event, meaning to organize it and oversee it while it is underway, is a transitive verb that takes a direct object:

> Are you running <sup>v.t.</sup>  the presentation <sup>d.o.</sup>  tomorrow?

The volleyball games themselves are not organizing anything. Someone is running *them*.

The volleyball games **are being run** simultaneously (by someone, e.g. by the school athletic department, or by the league).

In your example, the verb is intransitive, and it does not have the meaning of the transitive verb. Intransitive **run** means "to be underway, to be in progress, to be operating (properly)".

Comment: This is the same sense of "running" that we see in "a show running on Broadway" or "a program running on a server".

Comment: Indeed, Gary, if we abstract it.